# roles are not being changed for the mentioned user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When a staff does !mute @user time , it should give the role Muted and take away the role Speaker, this does not happen though, instead everything else happens and the roles are not given or taken away.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const ms = require('ms');


const token = '';

const PREFIX = '!';


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is active!');
})

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'mute':
            if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("You cannot run this command");
            let mperson = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]));
            if(!mperson) return  message.reply("I cannot find the user " + mperson)

            var mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("718166462862196777");
            var muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("717606607910993930");


            if(!muterole) return message.reply("Couldn't find the mute role.")


            let time = args[2];
            if(!time){
                return message.reply("You didnt specify a time!");
            }

            mperson.roles.add(mainrole).catch(console.error)
            mperson.roles.remove(muterole).catch(console.error);


            message.channel.send(`${mperson.user} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)

            setTimeout(function(){

                mperson.roles.add(mainrole)
                mperson.roles.remove(muterole);
                console.log(muterole)
                message.channel.send(`${mperson.user} has been unmuted.`)
            }, ms(time));



        break;
    }


});



bot.login(token);
```

The roles that I want to add and remove from the mentioned player do not change, any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Any errors logged? is this v11 or v12?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `mperson.roles.add(mainrole).catch(console.error)` to `mperson.roles.add("717631710761844757").catch(console.error)` and now everything works. This is discord.js v12.